# Error creating a subscription and/or schedule - EXECUTE permission was denied on the object

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-subscription

Trying to create a subscription and/or schedule in reporting services. I keep getting this error when I click ok. What's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually asked this question so I could answer it since it was such a pain.

In my case, we had migrated the reporting databases to a new server several years ago. Everything worked and we never needed to create a subscription so we never realized these features weren't actually working.

I found the answer here:

[How to: Create the RSExecRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281308(v=sql.105).aspx)

When we migrated, we created the RSExecRole on master, so most features worked, but apparently we had neglected to create the role in msdb (which is what is used for the job scheduling etc.).

I followed the instructions and everything worked, with one caveat. That link is missing one critical piece of information, which is that after you add the RSExecRole to master and msdb, you need to add them as Roles to the NETWORK SERVICE, or whatever account you have running your reporting server.